# break a matrix to sub-matrices with equal 2nd column without using for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix, L, with two columns. I want to find its sub-matrices have equal values on their 2nd column. I want to do that using MATLAB without any for loop.
example:

```
L=[1 2;3 2;4 6;5 3;7 3;1 3;2 7;9 7]
```

then the sub-matrices are:

```
[1 2;3 2] , [4 6] , [5 3;7 3;1 3] and [2 7;9 7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `arrayfun` + `unique` to get that -

```
[~,~,labels] = unique(L(:,2),'stable')
idx = arrayfun(@(x) L(labels==x,:),1:max(labels),'Uniform',0)
```

Display output -

```
>> celldisp(idx)
idx{1} =
     1     2
     3     2
idx{2} =
     4     6
idx{3} =
     5     3
     7     3
     1     3
idx{4} =
     2     7
     9     7
```

Comment: Oh by the way, I don't think arrayfun is a vectorized/no loop solution! Anyway you can't have a vectorized solution if your output isn't regularly shaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accumarray` directly or with a sorted array, depending on you want the order of the rows to be stable, or the order of the submatricxes to be stable.

Say you want the rows to be stable:

```
>> [L2s,inds] = sort(L(:,2));
>> M = accumarray(L2s,inds,[],@(v){L(v,:)});
>> M(cellfun(@isempty,M)) = [];  % remove empty cells
>> celldisp(M)
M{1} =
     1     2
     3     2
M{2} =
     5     3
     7     3
     1     3
M{3} =
     4     6
M{4} =
     2     7
     9     7
```